# Django/Django Channels - weird looking json response with double \ between each field

Tags: json, django, django-channels, django-jsonfield

Hello I'm trying to do a real time friend request notification system and having this weird looking json response. I'm new to backend development and django (1st year software engineering student). Im just wondering if this is normal since i havent seen anything like this and if theres a way to fix it. Ive worked on a chat app before but it was just all text messages and so I got confused when it comes to django models. I have tried multiple ways I found but only this works. I think it might be because I called json.dumps twice but if i remove either of them, it wont work. Thank you

When a user sends a friend request, this is what i got back from the web socket(with double \ for each field)
[image]

Heres the code
//views.py

```
class SendRequestView(views.APIView):
permission_class = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    receiver_username = self.kwargs['receiver_username']
    if receiver_username is not None:
        receiver = get_object_or_404(User, username=receiver_username)
        request = ConnectRequest.objects.create(sender=self.request.user, receiver=receiver)
        notification = ConnectNotification.objects.create(type='connect request', receiver=receiver, initiated_by=self.request.user)
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        channel = f'notifications_{receiver.username}'
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            channel, {
                'type': 'notify',
                'notification': json.dumps(ConnectNotificationSerializer(notification).data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
            }
        )
        data = {
            'status': True,
            'message': 'Success',
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

// consumer.py

```
class ConnectNotificationConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

async def connect(self):
    user = self.scope['user']
    group_layer = f'notifications_{user.username}'
    await self.accept()
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(group_layer, self.channel_name)

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    user = self.scope['user']
    group_layer = f'notifications_{user.username}'
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(group_layer, self.channel_name)

async def notify(self, event):
    notification = event['notification']
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
             'notification': notification
        })
    )
```

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: hi, the json response i got just looks not right. if you have a look at the screenshot, theres \ between the fields. So im just wondering if i did something wrong because it sucks going back and looking for the problem when i move on to the front end of the project

Comment: The \ are called "escape characters". Long story short, they indicate to the computer that the following character (the double quote) isn't an attempt to end the whole string (which is surrounded by double quotes). If you didn't have the slashes, whatever program is reading the json would assume it ends right after the opening curly brace, because there's a double quote there. Does that make sense?

Comment: Make total sense. Thank you very much